# Azure web service and Django log

Tags: python, django, azure, logging, django-models

I got some confuse question for writing log....

Below are my setting.py:

```js
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
.....
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.getenv('LOGFILE', 'django.log')
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        }
    }
}
```

** I want passes all INFO messages to django.log.

It will correctly write django.log when I running server at localhost test.

After I publish to Azure web app service, and set the "Application setting " => "App settings", add new path LOGFILE D:\home\site\wwwroot\logfiles\django.log.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDweD.png)

I send a few request to my app service,  then log in DebugConsole to watch the D:\home\site\wwwroot\logfiles\django.log file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D08VR.png)

There has no any content in this log file (django.log), and I try to modify it at DebugConsole, it will occurs ERROR 409 confict: Could not write to local resource 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\logfiles\django.log' due to error 'The process cannot access the file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\logfiles\django.log' becaure it is being used by another process.'.

It seem like Django cannot write anything in django.log or permission issue? How can I do?
Could someone help for this problem?

Comment: According to the offical blog [Debug Django Web Application in Azure Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/08/04/debug-django-web-application-in-azure-web-apps/), please switch `DEBUG` option to `FALSE` and try again. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Ifound the solution here:
http://azaleasays.com/2014/05/01/django-logging-with-rotatingfilehandler-error/

In short: launch the server with:
python manage.py runserver --noreload